# sqlldr ORA-01722: invalid number because of decimal number in a csv column

Tags: shell, csv, unix, loader, sql-loader

I am trying to load data from a csv file into an orcale table.
I am using the sqlldr with an control file
Everything works fine but in some cases the row doesnt get loaded because of an decimal number.
So in oracle Table the column is : Number(10) - this shouldnt be the problem
and my control file looks like this: (their are about 15 more columns but basically its about column quantity_1

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=1)
LOAD DATA 
 INFILE *
 APPEND
 INTO TABLE ..
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ";" OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
(
 Quantity_1, Quantity_2, Quantity_3,
)
```

In the csv file the rows for quantity_1 are like

```
2.58
4343
232
1212
```

and for the first row he gives the error:

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Can anybody help with this??

Comment: why should this help?

Comment: Do you have your language settings with decimal delimiter, different than dot?

Comment: @Romeo Ninov sorry i dont understand how to check those settings in the csv files their has to be the dot also in the table

Comment: No, I talk about your environment. For example in Bulgarian decimal delimiter is **comma**, not **dot**.

Comment: @RomeoNinov yes its also dot.

Comment: Check what is set for oracle. And try to execute command on this way: `LC_ALL=C sqlload .......`

Comment: it also did not work sorry

Comment: How did you define the data type of this column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your column defined as number(10), it should have rounded to 3 on insert. I suspect your real data is larger that 2.58.  Anyway your column should be defined as number(12,2), that is, a total of 12 digits long, 2 of those to the left of the decimal point.  i.e.  9999999999.99